# Command to remove all roles and add specific role to mentioned user

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js

I'm looking to create a command where the mentioned user will have all their roles removed and one specific role added. I'm having some difficulting with permissions and guild syntax.

The current code I've got is:

```
    name: 'megabean',
    description: 'makes Craig megabean people',
    execute(message, args){

        let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);
        
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} has **MEGABEANED** ${args [0]}. Say goodbye to your perms
**Reason for MEGABEAN:** ${args.splice(1).join(" ")} `)
            .then(guild.roles.set([]))
            .then(guild.roles.add(['741934348273451032']))
    
    }                
}
```

Currently, the client is not defined although I have
const client = new Discord.Client(); in my main.js file

I'm just looking for some info on how to better approach this task. Sorry if I may seem somewhat ill-prepared, so far research has not gotten me too far...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using your current client but creating a new instance, I'd suggest you pass your existing client as a function argument to it (using `execute(message, args, client)`, you could also login in this file again but I'd be careful with that as it can have unwanted side-effects. Do you also need help with removing the roles?

EDIT: For removing roles:

```js
message.member.roles.remove(message.member.roles); //remove all
message.member.roles.add(message.guild.roles.cache.get("role ID here")); //add the specific role
```

That's all.

Comment: I am definitely looking for help with role removals and adding roles to a mentioned user. That was just a poor error for forgetting to add client. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Bobfrog93 I made an edit on how you can achieve this

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again. Sorry for sounding so annoying, but the code doesn't seem to be removing and adding correctly - I'm looking for the code to go  !command .@mention reason and then have the .@mention user get all their roles removed then one added rather than the person calling the command having their roles altered. All good if you want to leave this with me, just not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: In this case it's applied to the author (the message.member), if you want this for another user, you can fetch the member using `message.guild.members.cache.get(message.mentions.users.first().id)` for example (I know it's very verbose). You can find more on this on discord.js.org, where the official documentation can be found

Comment: You can condense that to `message.mentions.members.first()`

Comment: You can also shorten `message.member.roles.remove(message.member.roles)` to `message.member.roles.set([])`